# Emberjs String not working with javascript string

Tags: ember.js

If I do `var str1 = "a string"` then I get a string literal (for want of a better term) when I look at the string in the debugger. i.e. it just displays "a string"

However if i do `var str2 = new Ember.String("another string")` then it appears as a String object with the chars listed as array items rather than just as "another string"

This is a problem because if i have an array like  `var myarray = ["str1", "str2","str3"]` and do  `myarray.contains(myvar)` it won't work if myvar is of type String.

Now I came across this because of an action handler where I had passed "this" and found it to have become type String. What on earth is going on! 
How can I turn my String back into a raw js string so it can be used in lookups in my array of constants?

Comment: Can you create a failing bin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object you're getting is not an 'Ember string', it's just a Javascript string object created via `new String('')`. I don't know why you're coming across one, but if you do, just convert it to a string primitive. You can either do that with the `toString()` method, or (the safer way) by just concatenating an empty string: `str2 + ''`.

Comment: Ah thanks, should have checked javascript first. I hadn't realised it distinguished string primitives and objects like Java